# Passing Oauth token data from service to component - Angular

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

I am trying to figure out how to pass a user token which is returned as part of a oauth2 implicit procedure in a service to a component which is the callback url so i can then use that token further in the piece.

service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User} from 'oidc-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    private manager: UserManager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());
    private user: User = null;

  constructor() {
    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
    }

  getClaims(): any {
  return this.user.profile;
    }

  getAuthorizationHeaderValue(): string {
      return `${this.user.token_type} ${this.user.access_token}`;
    }

  startAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
      return this.manager.signinRedirect();
    }

  completeAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
      return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
        console.log(user.access_token);
          this.user = user;
      });
    }

}

export function getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {
  return {
    authority: 'https://someserver.com',
    client_id: 'clientid',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope: "openid read write",
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: false,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html'
  };
}
```

This uses the OICD Oauth 2 library

the component code is below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router, NavigationCancel, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth-callback',
  templateUrl: './auth-callback.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth-callback.component.css'],
  providers: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthCallbackComponent implements OnInit {
  public accesstoken:any;

  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.completeAuthentication();
  }

}
```

as you can see the component calls completeAuthentication from the service successfully on init however i can't figure out how to pass the user_token from the service to the component. You will see this token reference in the completeAuthentication function of the service, and it does successfully console log at that point. At the moment all i am trying to do is console log that user token via the auth call back component to show that its being passed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the token from `completeAuthentication`:

```
completeAuthentication(): Promise<string> {
  return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
    console.log(user.access_token);
    this.user = user;
    return user.access_token;
  });
}
```

And in component call:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.authService.completeAuthentication().then(token => {
    console.log('Token in component:', token);
  });
}
```

Somehow more elegant and reusable way (so that other components might get token too, once it is received) would be to set the token to `BehaviorSubject` in the service and subscribe to that from anywhere.

To get that working, in `AuthService` define subject, observables and further modify `completeAuthentication`:

```
export class AuthService {
  private manager: UserManager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());
  private user: User = null;
  private _token = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  private _user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
  ...
  get user$(): Observable<User> {
    return this._user.asObservable().pipe(
      filter(val => val !== null),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      share());
  }

  get token$(): Observable<string> {
    return this._token.asObservable().pipe(
      filter(val => val !== null),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      share());
  }

  completeAuthentication(): Promise<string> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
      console.log(user.access_token);
      this.user = user;
      this._user.next(user);
      this._token.next(user.access_token);
      return user.access_token;
    });
  }
  ....
}
```

`_token` and `_user` are [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) that holds value for respective objects.

`token$` and `user$` are Observable streams of token and user respectively. They are filtered (by `filter` operator) to not return any value if it is `null`. If you wish to receive `null` as a sign that user is not logged in for example, just comment out those lines.

Anywhere in your code, supposing you inject the service, just use the observable to get latest value:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
  this.authService.token$.subscribe(token => {
    console.log('Got my token', token);
  });

  this.authService.user$.subscribe(user => {
    console.log('Got my user', user);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help that looks good, can you give a quick 101 how i would switch to a BehaviourSubject?

Comment: Hopefully explained how to do that with Observables, see modified answer.

Comment: it did apologies for delay in conforming the answer.